# Use python to connect to a php page and upload image

Tags: php, python, ftp

I would like to know if its possible to use python to connect to a certain site

(EX: http://www.example.com/python )

and upload an image from the computer.
Basically I have a python script that takes images from the webcam. Now after it takes the image how can i send that image to a webpage. If you tell me how to get it to connect to the page I can handle the rest. Thanks in advance!

THIS IS THE PYTHON SCRIPT AT HAND:

```
from VideoCapture import Device

cam = Device(devnum=1)
cam.saveSnapshot('image.jpg', timestamp=3, boldfont=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to learn "mechanize" library http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ It very easy to use.

This is example from one of my scripts.

```
def upload_and_get_data(username, password, image_filename):
    print image_filename, type(image_filename)
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.open("http://itmages.ru/user/login")
    form = browser.form = browser.forms().next()
    form["LoginForm[username]"] = username
    form["LoginForm[password]"] = password
    login_response = browser.submit()

    # file uploading
    form = browser.form = browser.forms().next()
    form.add_file(open(image_filename, "r"),
                  filename=os.path.basename(image_filename))
    send_response = browser.submit()

    table_regex = re.compile('<table class="stat".*?<input.*?</table>')
    table_data_text = table_regex.findall(
        send_response.get_data().replace("\n", " "))[0]
    table_data_regex = re.compile(
        '<tr> *<td.*?<b>([^<]*)</b></td> *<td>(.*?)</td> *</tr>')
    table_data = dict(table_data_regex.findall(table_data_text))
    return table_data
```

Comment: if i add this function to my script how can I use the image from `VideoCapture` and put it into the `image_filename` variable?

Comment: do you save your image on disk? If yes, you must know image's filename. Just pass those file contents and it's name to add_file. Otherwise, use StringIO and some spoof filename.

Comment: maybe i don't understood you. This method works with forms enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @werehuman Okay but my issue is how to pass the name to add_file. Lets say i stored the location to the image as `f`. would the function then be: `def upload_and_get_data(username, password, f):`?

Comment: If he has a URL and an API he can build against why would he rely on the presentation layer of the form instead?

Comment: i wrote whole function just as sample, that "mechanize" is easy. You need to write code similar to three accentuated statements: Open page with mechanize.Browser, find form, add file to it and submit form. But if you pass `f` to `upload_and_get_data` as third argument, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `urllib2` for this.  Basically build up a [`urllib2.Request`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) with the URL to the PHP script, and then `add_data` to add the image data that you want to submit.

**edit**: you can follow the examples [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/), and specifically [this example](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/#posting-form-data) to help understand the full process

Comment: Tip for the OP: You'll be using a POST request to send the image data, not GET.

Comment: this is great but can you further explain how to `add_data`. I am fairly new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Open the file, and use urllib:

```
imgfile = open("image.jpg", "rb")
urllib.urlopen("http://www.example.com/", imgfile.read())
```